# AWS Lambda and API Gateway - How to take export for these together to be checked in the git hub as a repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I want to take export of the all the Lambda funcitons alonwith the api gateway from aws console. This export we need to save in github for versioning and also this should be easily importable in aws console in case we want to copy these in some new region at aws. Please help how this can be done alongwith examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is to go for infrastructure as code.

You can [import existing resources to a CloudFormation template](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/).

Afterwards, you got your infrastructure as code and you can easily replicate it to other regions. Also, maintainability is increased and error proneness reduced.